# Sintaxe ':value' no array

Tags: php, array, laravel, sintaxe

Eu vi essa sintaxe no laravel, na área de 'resources/lang', onde estão pré configuradas mensagens de autenticação. E me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
<?php

return [

   'throttle' => 'Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds.',

];
```

Onde está escrito ':seconds', eu gostaria de saber, da onde vem esse valor e como exibi-lo corretamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php 
Adicione esse metodo de sobrescrita

```
 /**
 * Determina a quantidade de tentativas de acesso caso a senha esteja errada
 * 6 Tentativas por 30 minutos
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function hasTooManyLoginAttempts(Request $request)
{
    return $this->limiter()->tooManyAttempts(
        $this->throttleKey($request), 6, 30 
    );
}
```

Esse valor vem do CORE do Laravel, esse método acima serve para sobrescrever o codigo padrão. Se você estiver usando o AUTH corretamente dentro do Laravel, essa mensagem será exibida automaticamente, e o valor a ser mostrado sera se acordo com oque você editou.
Essa estrutura serve para que você consiga adicionar pacotes de tradução dentro do seu projeto.

Aqui vai um repositório para ajudar na tradução do seu projeto.

https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang

Comment: Eu poderia fazer fazer ou usar esse tipo de sistema em um projeto do zero?

Comment: Você diz o auth? ou você esta falando do repositório?

Comment: Eu falo assim, um projeto sem laravel, se eu quiser fazer isso por exemplo:  <?php return [  'welcome' => 'Welcome :user'  ] ?> Ouput: Welcome, Fulano

Comment: Pode sim, um exemplo mais simples é esse do site php.net : http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.http-auth.php.  , acredito que algo mais simples, ou mais seco que esse outro exemplo , não compensa, pois estamos falando de segurança, e essas soluções são testadas e desenvolvidas já a um bom tempo, por uma comunidade grande.

Comment: Realmente, obrigado